# Is 1.5 enough time at LAX to make my connection to international flight?

Tags: transit, short-connections, lax

I'm flying Delta and making a connection at LAX between a domestic flight to a departing international flight? Do I need to reclear security and/or checked bags?
Is the 1.5 hours that Delta reserved sufficiant? I arrive at 11 pm on Wednesday and leave at 12:30 am, and have a single ticket for the entire journey.

Comment: For those voting this as a duplicate IT IS NOT!!  The question you're listing as a dup is for a different airline in a different terminal. LAX has 9 terminals (some of which are connected airside, others are not), and dozens of airlines.  UA->UA as per the question you're dup'ing against is very different to DL->DL

Answer (score 2):

Delta recently moved to terminal 2 and terminal 3 at LAX.  If your outbound flight is a codeshare on another airline (with a DL flight number), then it might also depart from the "International" terminal, also known as the "Tom Bradley International Terminal", TBIT, or Terminal B.

As both flights are on Delta (or a codeshare partner) you will not need to re-check bags - they will be transfers to your new flight for you.

Depending on which terminal you land in and depart from you may need to move between terminals.  Terminal 2, 3 and B are NOT connected airside, however there is a air-side shuttle that can be used to move between these terminals without the need to clear security.  You should be careful not to accidentally leave the secured area, or you will need to re-clear security which could take some time (although likely not at that time of night)

90 minutes should be plenty of time to make this connection, even if you need to catch the bus between terminals. Of course, that presumes that your inbound flight is not delayed - a delay of anything more than about an hour could turn this into a very tight connection, but of course that's always possible regardless of how much time you leave!

Comment: Not related to the OP but Terminal 4 at LAX is connected airside to Terminal B.

Comment: T4-T8 and TBIT are all interconnected, however Delta no longer uses any of these terminals so as you've said it's not relevant to this question.